# tikz: draw arrow till above of middle of below rectangle

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

How to take the arrow just above the middle of rectangle R2 and down to R2.north (at center of top)?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-uml}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart,positioning,fit}
\usepackage{pgf-umlsd}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[text width=3cm]                       (A)  at (0,0)               {\tiny AAA};
        
        \node[anchor=north west , text width=1cm]   (A1) at (A.south west)      {\tiny BBB};
        \node[anchor=west       , text width=1cm]   (A2) at (A1.east)           {\tiny CCC};
        \node[anchor=west       , text width=1cm]   (A3) at (A2.east)           {\tiny DDD};
        
        \node[anchor=north west , text width=1cm]   (A4) at (A1.south west)     {\tiny EEE};
        \node[anchor=west       , text width=1cm]   (A5) at (A4.east)           {\tiny FFF};
        \node[anchor=west       , text width=1cm]   (A6) at (A5.east)           {\tiny };
        
        \node [inner sep=0pt,
        draw,
        rounded corners,
        fit = (A)(A1)(A2)(A3)(A4)(A5)(A6)
        ] (A13) {}; 
        
        \draw   (A1.north west) -- (A3.north east)
        (A1.south west) -- (A3.south east);    
        
        \node[below left = 1.0cm and 0.5cm of A13.south, text width=1cm]    (B1) {\tiny GGG};
        \node[below =0cm of B1, text width=1cm] (B2) {\tiny HHH};
        \node [inner sep=0pt,
        draw,
        rounded corners,
        fit = (B1)(B2)
        ] (B6) {}; 
        
        \draw[gray,->] (A6.center)  -- ++(east:1.0) -- ++(down:0.5) -- ++(west:1.5) -- ++(down:0.4);
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Replace the last part of the last `\draw` command by `-| (B6.north);`. That should do it.

Answer (score 2):

For this, you can make use of the `-|` connector, which (unlike `--` that draws just a straight line connecting two nodes) draws first a horizontal and than a vertical line, so that two nodes are connected at right angles. There is also the counterpart `|-` that first draws the vertical line. Then, you can easily let the arrow end right on top of `B6` (which is how you named in the code the node you denoted with R2 in your picture) using `B6.north`.

The full code would then be (I commented out two packages that are not needed and of which I don't have the first one anyways):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage{tikz-uml}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart,positioning,fit}
%\usepackage{pgf-umlsd}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[text width=3cm]                       (A)  at (0,0)               {\tiny AAA};
        
        \node[anchor=north west , text width=1cm]   (A1) at (A.south west)      {\tiny BBB};
        \node[anchor=west       , text width=1cm]   (A2) at (A1.east)           {\tiny CCC};
        \node[anchor=west       , text width=1cm]   (A3) at (A2.east)           {\tiny DDD};
        
        \node[anchor=north west , text width=1cm]   (A4) at (A1.south west)     {\tiny EEE};
        \node[anchor=west       , text width=1cm]   (A5) at (A4.east)           {\tiny FFF};
        \node[anchor=west       , text width=1cm]   (A6) at (A5.east)           {\tiny };
        
        \node [inner sep=0pt,
        draw,
        rounded corners,
        fit = (A)(A1)(A2)(A3)(A4)(A5)(A6)
        ] (A13) {}; 
        
        \draw   (A1.north west) -- (A3.north east)
        (A1.south west) -- (A3.south east);    
        
        \node[below left = 1.0cm and 0.5cm of A13.south, text width=1cm]    (B1) {\tiny GGG};
        \node[below =0cm of B1, text width=1cm] (B2) {\tiny HHH};
        \node [inner sep=0pt,
        draw,
        rounded corners,
        fit = (B1)(B2)
        ] (B6) {}; 
        
        \draw[gray,->] (A6.center)  -- ++(east:1.0) -- ++(down:0.5) -- ++(west:1.5) -| (B6.north);
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]